# How to close v-select menu on click with prepend-items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Inside my v-select menu, I added a `template` with 2 `v-list-items` :

```
                        <v-select
                             :items=clients
                             dense
                             item-text="full_name"
                             item-value="id"
                             label="Search by client"
                             outlined
                             v-model="clientSearch"
                        >
                            <template v-slot:prepend-item>
                                <v-list-item
                                     ripple
                                     @click="selectNone()">
                                    <v-list-item-content>
                                        <v-list-item-title>None</v-list-item-title>
                                    </v-list-item-content>
                                </v-list-item>
                                <v-list-item
                                     ripple
                                     @click="selectAll">
                                    <v-list-item-content>
                                        <v-list-item-title>All</v-list-item-title>
                                    </v-list-item-content>
                                </v-list-item>
                            </template>
                        </v-select>
```

Items within the `v-select` values react with the close-on-click property set by default, but not the the 2 others `v-list-item`.

How can I add the property close-on-click to the items inside the `template` so the v-menu closes no mater which item is selected ?

Answer (score 4):

```
 <v-select
 .
 .
 :menu-props="{
   closeOnClick: true,
   closeOnContentClick: true,
  }"
>
</vselect>
```

"closeOnContentClick: true" make the list as wish you are wish:)

Comment: Explain your answer.

Comment: Only `closeOnContentClick: true` was necessary for my case.

Answer (score 0):

So far I didn't see yet vuetify had this in their docs. What I did on it last time is to just push a new item in your current data and assigned an id just for an indicator. Maybe not the good way but will solve your problem as of now. Like this one

```
this.clients.push(
    {id:0, full_name:'All'},
    {id: -1, full_name:'None'}
)
```

Comment: ```this.clients``` is being set with vuex therefore I cannot update it directly that way.

Answer (score 0):

adding
:menu-props="{
closeOnClick: true,
closeOnContentClick: true,
}"
as mentioned above works for me